# Can't Access Entity In Core Data From Another View Controller

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I am a novice Objective-C programmer and core data user.  This is my first time using core data.  What I am trying to do is put entities in a core data database and then retrieve and edit them in another View Controller.
Here is the code in my ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];

    NSString *documentName = @"myDocument";
    NSURL *url = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path] ];
    if(fileExists)
    {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            if(!success) NSLog(@"Error (this isn't printed)");
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            if(!success) NSLog(@"Error (this isn't printed)");
        }];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = document.managedObjectContext;

        QuestionResponse *question1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"QuestionResponse" inManagedObjectContext: context];
        QuestionResponse *question2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"QuestionResponse" inManagedObjectContext: context];
        QuestionResponse *question3 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"QuestionResponse" inManagedObjectContext: context];
        QuestionResponse *question4 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"QuestionResponse" inManagedObjectContext: context];

        question1.question = @"What is your favorite food?";
        question2.question = @"Who is your favorite fictional character?";
        question3.question = @"Name someone who loves you:";
        question4.question = @"What is your favorite place (real or fictional)?";

        question1.order = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        question2.order = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
        question3.order = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
        question4.order = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];
        question1.group = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        question2.group = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        question3.group = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
        question3.group = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
        question1.display = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        question2.display = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        question3.display = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        question4.display = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

        NSFetchRequest* request2 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@ "QuestionResponse"];
        NSError* error2 = nil;
        NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error2];
        if (!results || !results.count){
            NSLog(@"No elements (this isn't printed)");
        }
        if(results.count == 4)
        {
            NSLog(@"We have four entities (this is what is printed)");
        }        
    }
}
```

In my AnswerViewController.m this is the code:

```
 - (IBAction)answerQuestion1:(id)sender {    
    //File creation begins here (same as in View Controller)
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
    NSString *documentName = @"myDocument";    
    NSURL *url = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path] ];
    if(fileExists)
    {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            if(!success) NSLog(@"Error");
        }];
        NSLog(@"File Exists (this is printed)");
    }
    else
    {
        [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            if(!success)NSLog(@"There has been a problem (this isn't printed)");
        }];
    }
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = document.managedObjectContext;
    //File Creation ends here

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchRequest* request2 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@ "QuestionResponse"];
    NSError* error2 = nil;
    NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error2];
    if (!results || !results.count){
        NSLog(@"No entities (this is what is printed");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Some entities (this isn't printed)");
    }
}
```

In my ViewController.m the core data has four elements but when I try to access them in AnswereViewController.m there is nothing in core data.  Why is this happening and how can I access my elements from AnswereViewController.m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use CoreData successfully, you have to first understand the flow of it. In essence, CoreData can be broken down into two main parts:

1. the database (so the .sqlite file itself)
2. the persistent store coordinator (henceforth known as psc)

What you have done so far in ViewController.m is that you have told the compiler to insert your 4 objects into your managedObjectContext. This gets done on a psc level. The psc acts like a scratchpad for all of your database changes. Until you actually tell it to save it, it will only live in the psc and not in your .sqlite file. What you need to do then is to call:

```
[context save:&error2]
```

This will tell the compiler to push your current status of the psc into the database so it persists.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand core data better.  I added:[context save:&error2] after I assigned the values of the properties of the questions.  It still isn't working though.  Is there anything else I don't understand or could have done wrong?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is the context you are performing the NSFetchRequest from is incorrect. Up to my understanding, I don't believe it is correct to be accessing your NSManagedObjectContext through an NSManagedObject. The NSManagedObjectContext you should be accessing from should be from the coredata controller itself, and not from an NSManagedObject.

Heres a reference for you as to how I recommend you structure your coredata:
https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-core-data-migration